# mitigate static html pages from xampp to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, static, xampp, web

I have developed a website using xampp. And I want it to replace a current website on Wordpress.

I tried looking for tutorial/steps online, have tried a few, nothing seems to work.

I desperately need to upload it, so it would replace the current website. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: the website is fully static, no database is required.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything in the wordpress folder (or move it to a subfolder for the time being while you test) via ftp and upload the html site.  As long as your new site has a index.html/index.htm it will replace the wordpress site at the url.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Create Template in theme folder
Step 2. Give Template at the top of the page Like this 
Step 3. Place all Html code below the template name
Step 4. Go to wordpress dashborad choose your template 'CustomPageT1' from dropdown 
Further Detail check the link below
For Example: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/